# Unable to save jquery cookies

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

hey friends i have make an chatbox with jquery but it is unable to save cookies
please look my cade and tell me that why it is not working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".trigger").click(function() {

        $(".chat").show("fast");

        $(this).showClass("active");

        $.cookie('chatbox', 'open', {
            expires: 7
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: OP probably meant `addClass`, try with addClass and make sure you've included the [`jQuery.cookie`](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) script correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie code you posted was invalid. Use this:

```
$.cookie('chatbox', 'open');
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), `$.cookie('name', 'value', optionsObject)` it seems very valid to me.